# how to modify python LoggerAdapter

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to modify the log context in python using LoggerAdapter. First time it set to "PRE_SYSTEM_BOOT". But subsequent modification with the context is not taking effect. Can someone explain why the context string change not taking effect ?

```
import logging
extra = {'proc_context': 'PRE_SYSTEM_BOOT'}
def get_logger():
    format_str="%(proc_context)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=format_str)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
    return logger

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = get_logger()
    logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
    # preboot
    logger.debug("init context")
    # boot
    extra = {'proc_context': 'SYSTEM_BOOT'}
    logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
    logger.debug("system contex")
    extra = {'proc_context': 'SYSTEM_POST_BOOT'}
    logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
    #post boot
    logger.debug("system booted")
```

Output:

```
root@ubuntu-~# python python_log.py
PRE_SYSTEM_BOOT: init context
PRE_SYSTEM_BOOT: system contex
PRE_SYSTEM_BOOT: system booted
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:~#
```

Expected:

> PRE_SYSTEM_BOOT: init context
>
> SYSTEM_BOOT: system contex
>
> POST_SYSTEM_BOOT: system booted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get logger instance before set logger adapter:

```
import logging
extra = {'proc_context': 'PRE_SYSTEM_BOOT'}
def get_logger():
    format_str="%(proc_context)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=format_str)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
    return logger

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger = get_logger()
    # preboot
    logger.debug("init context")
    # boot
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    extra = {'proc_context': 'SYSTEM_BOOT'}
    logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
    logger.debug("system contex")
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    extra = {'proc_context': 'SYSTEM_POST_BOOT'}
    logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
    #post boot
    logger.debug("system booted")
```